# Proof that every Riemannian geodesic is locally minimizing

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I'am reading John M.Lee's Riemannian Manifolds-An Introduction to curvature, p.107

[image]

Here, 'radial geodesic' means a geodesic starting at $p$ and lying in a normal neighborhood of $p$. (his book p.78)

And an open set $W \subset M$ is called 'uniformly normal' if there exists some $\delta > 0$ such that $W$ is contained in a geodesic ball of radius $\delta$ around each of its points(his book p.78)

I'm trying to understand the underlined statement.
Any two geodesic lying in the same geodesic ball are same? Or perhaps, is there any relation between them so we can deduce that "$\gamma$ must itself be this minimizing geodesic"?

Can anyone helps for proving this statement rigorously?

Comment: Does the text have a "local uniqueness" result for geodesics, i.e. that geodesics are locally unique? This should follow from a local uniqueness theory to solutions of differential equations.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found an associated literature :  http://perso.eleves.ens-rennes.fr/people/Gwendal.Soisnard/Rapports_2016/Thomas_Franzinetti_38996.pdf

In the pdf, p.28, Proposition 3.5, the author states :

**Proposition 3.5** (Radial Geodesic) Let $\mathcal{U}$ be a normal neighborhood of $p \in M$. Then, for all $q\in \mathcal{U}$, there exist a unique geodesic $\sigma_{pq} : [0,1] \to M$ from $p$ to $q$ in $\mathcal{U}$. This geodesic is said to be radial.

So this proposition 3.5 explains why we attached 'the' before 'radial geodesic  from $q_1$ to $q_2$' in the proof of the above theorem 6.12.

Let me explain why the underlined statement is true.

Since the restriction $\gamma_{|[t_1,t_2]}$ is a geodesic from $q_1$ to $q_2$ lying in the same geodesic ball, it is same as 'the' radial geodesic from $q_1$ to $q_2$ up to reparametrization. By the proposition 6.10(in john Lee's book), the radial geodesic is minimizing. So $\gamma_{|[t_1,t_2]}$ is also minimizing

Answer (score 5):

Hmmm ... you're right -- I didn't explain this well at all. It doesn't follow directly from Proposition 6.10; instead there are two steps to the argument: first note that the proposition on properties of normal coordinates (Prop. 5.11 in the first edition, 5.24 in the second) shows that every geodesic segment lying in a geodesic ball and starting at the center of the ball is
part of a radial geodesic, and then Prop. 6.10 in the first edition (6.11 in the second) shows that each
radial geodesic segment is minimizing.

Embarassingly, this same omission was carried over to the second edition of my book, where I thought I had eradicated all of these logical leaps. Oh well.

I've added corrections for both editions [here](http://sites.math.washington.edu/%7Elee/Books/RM/). Thanks for pointing this out.

**EDIT:** Here are some answers to the questions you asked comments.

> First, since geodesic ball is a normal neighborhood, by the
> definition of radial geodesic( your book p.78)every geodesic segment
> lying in a geodesic ball is automatically radial geodesic?

No, every geodesic lying in a geodesic ball ***and starting at the center of that ball*** is automatically a radial geodesic.

> So, if
> Prop.6.10 means that every radial geodesic segment is minimizing, then
> in particular $\gamma_{[t_1,t_2]}$ is minimizing. Is this argument correct?

Yes. (A better notation is $\gamma|_{[t_1,t_2]}$ to denote the restriction of $\gamma$ to the interval $[t_1,t_2]$.)

> Second, but..you wrote in prop.6.10 that " 'the' radial geodesic from
> $p$ to $q$ is the unique minimizing curve from $p$ to $q$ in $M$. " Is
> there a special reason for attaching 'the' to radial geodesic? What is
> 'the' radial geodesic?

The definition of "radial geodesic" (which appears just after Proposition 5.11) is any geodesic starting at $p$ and lying in a normal neighborhood of $p$. Proposition 5.11 shows that they all are given by $\gamma_V(t) = (tV^1,\dots,tV^n)$ for various choices of $(V^1,\dots,V^n)$. You can check that for any point $q$ in that neighborhood, up to reparametrization, there is exactly one such geodesic from $p$ to $q$. (One such parametrization is obtained by taking $(V^1,\dots,V^n)$ to be the coordinates of $q$, and taking the parameter interval to be $[0,1]$.)

> And.. as your answers, for a given geodesic segment (in particular,
> $\gamma_{[t_1,t_2]}$) in a geodesic ball, can we provide an explicit radical
> geodesic that has the geodesic(γ[t1,t2]) as a part? How?

As I noted above, the radial geodesic from $p$ to $q$ is $\gamma(t) = (tV^1,\dots,tV^n)$, where $(V^1,\dots,V^n)$ are the coordinates of $q$ and $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$.

> (And what is the rigorous definition of "a part of radial geodesic"?

Just the restriction of the radial geodesic to a subinterval of its domain.

> And in our argument, you suggested to use Prop 5.11 (first edition).
> And it just states that we can represent the $\gamma_V$ in normal coordinate
> as simple form. How to apply Prop.5.11 to our argument. Perhaps, we
> maybe use the Prop. 5.7-(b)

Actually, the very definition of "radial geodesic" is "a geodesic
starting at $p$ and lying in a normal neighborhood of $p$." What I used Proposition 5.11 for is the claim that there's only one such geodesic from $p$ to $q$ (up to reparametrization, anyway), which follows from the explicit formula.

Comment: Yes. I have a confusion. First, since geodesic ball is a normal neighborhood, by the definition of radial geodesic( your book p.78)every geodesic segment lying in a geodesic ball is automatically radial geodesic? So, if Prop.6.10 means that every radial geodesic segment is minimizing, then in particular $\gamma_{[t_1, t_2]}$ is minimizing. Is this argument correct?

Comment: Second, but..you wrote in prop.6.10 that " 'the' radial geodesic from $p$ to $q$ is the unique minimizing curve from $p$ to $q$ in $M$. " Is there a special reason for attaching 'the' to radial geodesic? What is 'the' radial geodesic? And.. as your answers, for a given geodesic segment (in particular, $\gamma_{[t_1, t_2]}$) in  a geodesic ball, can we provide an explicit radical geodesic that has the geodesic($\gamma_{[t_1, t_2]}$) as a part? How? (And what is the rigorous definition of "a part of radial geodesic"?

Comment: And in our argument, you suggested to use Prop 5.11 (first edition). And it just states that we can represent the $\gamma _{V}$ in normal coordinate as simple form. How to apply  Prop.5.11 to our argument.  Perhaps, we maybe use the Prop. 5.7-(b).

Comment: @Plantation: These are too many questions to answer in comments. Let me edit my answer and put my replies there.

Comment: Yes, O.K. Thanks.

Comment: Uhm... Let me follow your answer. First, note that $\gamma|_{[t_1, t_2]}$ (or by considering its unique forward reparametrization $\tilde{\gamma} : [0, l] \to M$ (your book p.93) is starting at $q_1$ and lying in the geodesic ball  $\mathcal{N} :=\operatorname{exp}_{q_1}(B_{\delta}(0))$. So it is radial geodesic. So as you commented, if there is only one radial geodesic from $q_1$ to $q_2$ , then  $\gamma|_{[t_1, t_2]}$ is (up to reparametrization) same as the radial geodesic you provide (involving coordinate of $q $), and so it is minimizing.

Comment: So, key point is still "the uniqueness of radial geodesic from $q_1$ to $q_2$(up to reparametrization)", which similarly returns to our original question. Why this is true? To show the statement by applying prop.5.11, perhaps.. every radial geodesic from $q_1$ to $q_2$ is of the form $\gamma_V(t)$ for some initial tangent vector $V$?

Comment: Second question : You suggested that we can take 'the' radial geodesic explicitly considering the coordiantes of $q_2$. I guess another construction.
     ; i.e., first consider   $V = V^{i} \partial_i := \operatorname{exp}_{q_1} ^{-1}(q_2) \in B_{\delta}(0) \subseteq T_{q_1}M $ and let $\psi(t) := \operatorname{exp}_{q_1}(tV)$, where $t$ ranges from $0$ to $1$. This $\psi$ is same as your construction? And it is really geodesic? (I guess so by the Prop. 5.7 in your book).

Comment: And additionally, if my first argument works well, then the statement you mentioned that "$\gamma | _{[t_1, t_2]}$ is a 'part of' a radial geodesic$ is unnecessary?

Comment: @Plantation: I don't think you really need me to answer all of these questions. You have all the tools you need to figure this out for yourself.

Comment: O.K. I will try to it. Thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

Consider a set $S$ which is a geodesic ball of radius $r$ around $p$ and also a normal neighborhood of $p$. Since $S$ is a geodesic ball, it contains all geodesics of length at most $r$ starting at $p$. Since $S$ is a normal neighborhood of $p$, all geodesics within this neighborhood starting at $p$ end at different points. Hence, for any point $q$ within $S$, the geodesic within $S$ from $p$ to $q$ is shorter than any geodesic from $p$ to $q$ not within $S$.

Comment: Uhm..I can't understand until now :)  I can't understand why your second and third statements are true. And why your third argument is sufficient to show that $\gamma|_{[t_1, t_2]}$(in our image) is minimizing?.  From your statement, can we show that $\gamma|_{[t_1, t_2]}$ is also shorter than any geodesic from $q_1$ to $q_2$ 'within' $S$?                                Can you explain your argument more detail?

Comment: The second statement is true because the exponential map is a map from geodesics starting at p (enumerated by the tangent vectors at p) to their endpoints. Within a normal neighborhood, this map is injective by definition.

Comment: This argument shows that $\gamma|_{[t_1,t_2]}$ is the *only* geodesic from $q_1$ to $q_2$ within $S$, all others (if they exist) would leave $S$ at some point and are therefore longer.